# Pushing a file on github, not the whole branch

Tags: git, push, commit, pull

Here are the steps I am following to push/commit my changes of `file.txt` from my local to my staged branch :

1. `git add file.txt`
2. `git commit -m "my file is changed"`
3. `git push <my-remote> <my-branch>`

The problem is, the whole branch is pushed and merged, not only the changes in the file. How do I avoid this ? And how do I delete from the history of my commits this specific one ? so I can send a clean pull request to the master.

Comment: You don't push *files*, you push *commits*. Please explain more about what you hope to accomplish.

Comment: git is essential a lot of stroboscopic snapshots of your directory as a whole.

Comment: @MeriemBen: Why do you believe that using `commit <myfile.txt>` (which is, in my experience, rather rare syntax) is the fix? The procedure you propose for using it doesn't make much sense - you're saying you needed to stage your changes to the index, and then use a `commit` command that ignores the index. I'm additionally confused what  you mean when you say "staged branch", because this is not typical git terminology.  All of which may seem nit-picky, but if you have the basic concepts mixed up (as it seems you probably do) then proceeding without taking a step back to re-learn is risky

Answer (score 1):

That's not how git works.  Push is used to send all your changes that the remote branch does not have.  If you want to throw away all your other changes besides the commit named "my file is changed", you can do

```
git rebase -i $(git rev-parse origin/branch_name)
```

Set all the other commits to "d" for drop except for "my file is changed".  This will delete all the other commits and you can now push to push only that single commit.

However, if your goal is to keep those other commits, I'd suggest checking out a new branch from the head of your remote branch and cherry-picking your single commit onto there, creating your pull request from this new branch instead.

```
git checkout -b new_branch_name origin/branch_name
git cherry-pick commit_sha
git push -u origin new_branch_name
```

If you need to then remove the single commit from your original branch, just perform the first command I listed and drop that single commit instead of the others.

Comment: Is there a way to make a pull request for one specific commit ? because when I do a pull request the whole history of my commits appear and I only wish to place a request on one specific commit

Comment: @MeriemBen Pull requests are operated on a branch level.  For it to be effective for one specific commit, that commit should be the only commit different between your source and target branches.  Either of the 2 methods I outlined above will do what you need, depending on whether or not you want to hold on to your other changes.  However, since based on your other comment, you already pushed your current branch, so I would suggest the second method, and without modifying your original branch.

Answer (score 0):

When dev is your remote branch, try

```
git push origin HEAD:refs/for/dev
```